# Get html code and edit then load on to web view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to load a web site on a UIWebView which is not under my control and edit/add certain UI changes (Some texts, images, etc) to it. Can I do this within my iOS source code? I can't change the hosted html contents since them not under my control. 
If this cannot doable within iOS source code, please advice me the correct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Load the webpage into an `NSString`, make any modifications and then put the html into the `UIWebView`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
NSString *page = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

/* Make changes to page here */

[self.webView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that the site doesn't load correctly, images don't appear, links don't work, etc... I tried using this method because I wanted to add 'padding' (content inset) to the top of my WKWebView, but it doesn't really work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get the dom with JavaScript, manipulate, then inject back with JavaScript.

See [**`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a).

You can write your own full featured, minified JavaScript, then pass into using this method.

```
// Change body color of any HTML content inside a UIWebView.
NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementByTagName('body').backgroundColor = '#888';";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```